# How to prevent LibXML prettyprint from changing element values?

Tags: perl, libxml2, pretty-print

Consider this snippet:

```
my $PRSR = XML::LibXML->new();
my $PP = XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint->new(indent_string => "  ");
my $tmRawData = <DATA>;
my $tmDOM = $PRSR->load_xml(string => $tmRawData);
my $hm="SHA-1";
say $tmDOM->findvalue('//checksum[checksumMethod="' . $hm .'"]/checksumValue');
my $prettyxml = $PP->pretty_print($tmDOM->documentElement())->toString();
say $tmDOM->findvalue('//checksum[checksumMethod="' . $hm .'"]/checksumValue');
say $prettyxml;
__DATA__
<checksum> <checksumMethod>SHA-1</checksumMethod> <checksumValue>56db195fc75e93509133193bfe5608eaeef2c471</checksumValue> </checksum>
```

The first say will correctly print out the hash value. The second say will print an empty string. Obviously, pretty_print changes all element values by padding them with whitespace to look pretty when printed. I could use "contains" in the xpath to solve this the dirty way, but that would be, well, dirty.

Now my first (and so far, only) idea was to simply copy the DOM object so that pretty_print can mess up one but spare the other, like this:

```
my $PRSR = XML::LibXML->new();
my $PP = XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint->new(indent_string => "  ");
my $tmRawData = <DATA>;
my $tmDOM = $PRSR->load_xml(string => $tmRawData);
my $hm="SHA-1";
say $tmDOM->findvalue('//checksum[checksumMethod="' . $hm .'"]/checksumValue');
my $tmDOM2 = $tmDOM;
my $prettyxml = $PP->pretty_print($tmDOM2->documentElement())->toString();
say $tmDOM->findvalue('//checksum[checksumMethod="' . $hm .'"]/checksumValue');
__DATA__
<checksum> <checksumMethod>SHA-1</checksumMethod> <checksumValue>56db195fc75e93509133193bfe5608eaeef2c471</checksumValue> </checksum>
```

but this produces exactly the same result.

1. question: Why doesn't copying tmDOM to another variable tmDOM2 solve this?
2. question: Is there a way to prevent pretty_print from messing up element values?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think your $tmDOM is just a reference, copying the reference to another variable doesn't copy the underlying object. You'd need to deep copy it. Maybe use Storable qw(dclone); and then $tmDOM2 = dclone $tmDOM; ?

Comment: XML::LibXML::Node objects are pointers to C structs. `dclone` doesn't go deep enough. XML::LibXML::Node does provide a `cloneNode` method though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> question: Why doesn't copying tmDOM to another variable tmDOM2 solve this?

Because you're copying a reference. It's like this:

```
my $x = [ 1 .. 9 ];
my $y = $x;               # copy $x to $y to protect it from changes to $x
push @$x, 10;             # change $x
print "$_\n" for @$y;     # d'oh! we changed $y too
```

> question: Is there a way to prevent pretty_print from messing up element values?

Read the documentation. In particular, search for the `preserves_whitespace` option which allows you to tell XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint to preserve whitespace within particular elements.

Comment: So passing references to DOM objects along like dostuff(\$dom) is absolutely unnecessary? Because that's what I do all the time, because someone on SO told me that $dom will hold the complete structure, not just the reference...

Comment: All objects in Perl are references.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `cloneNode` method to get a new copy of the same DOM node.

```
my $PP        = 'XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint'->new( indent_string => '  ' );
my $tmRawData = <DATA>;
my $tmDOM     = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml( string => $tmRawData );
my $tmDOM2    = $tmDOM->cloneNode(1);                        # <--- HERE
my $hm        = 'SHA-1';
say '1: ', $tmDOM->findvalue("//checksum[checksumMethod='$hm']/checksumValue");
my $prettyxml = $PP->pretty_print($tmDOM->documentElement)->toString;
say '2: ', $tmDOM2->findvalue("//checksum[checksumMethod='$hm']/checksumValue");
say '3: ', $prettyxml;
```

Comment: Aha! Someone on SO told me that DOM-objects always hold the complete data, not just the reference. So I'm passing references along all the time in my code :). Good to know.